# Finding twice the same random pattern

Tags: javascript, string

How to find a character only if it is always followed by the same letter (random and unknown)?

For example:

> kelmqaetrstaeiii

E.g with the letter `a`, it is twice followed by the same letter `e`, so i would like it to be found, but with the following:

> kelmqaetrstafiii

We have `ae` and `af`, 2 differents letters after `a`, in this case nothing should be taken.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't fully follow your question, but it seems that regex alone may not be the right tool for this.

Comment: Aren't `ii` and `ii` in `iii` two pairs?

Comment: @JonasW. indeed, `a` was just an example

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OP specifically asked for a regular expression match, I'm curious why it was edited out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match the first letter, then use lookahead, match the second letter, and use backreferences:

```js
const re = /(\w)(?=(\w).+\1\2)/;
console.log('kelmqaetrstaeiii'.match(re)[0]);
console.log('kelmqaetrstafiii'.match(re));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the string and check if one of the pairs already appeared in the string:

```js
function hasPair(str) {
    const dupe = {};
    for (let index = 0; index < str.length - 1; index++) {
        const pair = str.substr(index, 2);
        if (dupe[pair])
            return pair;
        dupe[pair] = true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(
    hasPair("kelmqaetrstaeii"),
    hasPair("kelmqaetrstaii")
);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i just wanted to avoid to iterate over the string, and try to solve this using only regexes ;)

Comment: @cinn small hint: the regex engine also iterates the string ... ;)